# Split files into even smaller files from a previous split in a directory

Tags: shell, split, sh

I split a larger 42 million line file by 100000 lines and put it into /dev/shm/split/.

I need to split these into even smaller files by 1000 lines.

## 1 This is what I thought would work but only processes 1 file, not all of them:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in /dev/shm/split/file.txt.* ;

do

   find /dev/shm/split/ -type f -name $f -exec split -l 1000 {} /dev/shm/split/file1.txt. \;

done ;

echo "Split complete."
```

## 2 I also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

for f in /dev/shm/split/* ;

do

   split -l 1000 {} /dev/shm/split/file1.txt. ;

done ;

echo "Split complete."
```

## 3 I also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read file in * ; 

do

   split -l 1000 $file file1.txt.

done ;

echo "Split complete."
```

Number 1 produced 1 file processed through the split command. Number 2 did not produce anything. Number 3 seemed like it started processing by bringin the cursor to the next line, but when I checked using:

```
 wc -l /dev/shm/split/file1.*
```

...there were no results after about 3 minutes.

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: #3 is waiting for you to type input because that's what `read` does.

Comment: #2 doesn't even use `$f`.

Comment: In #1, -name $f won't work, because $f already has full absolute path of the file

Comment: I tried number 2 with $f and it split 1 file by 1000 lines. For number 3, do I need to run 'ls > whitelist' and use whiltelist as the input file? So after done ; < whitelist is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#3 with a few changes might work


ls *.txt | while read file
do
   echo "Splitting file $file"
   split -l 1000 $file $file.
done

echo "Split complete."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

```
find /dev/shm/split/ -type f -exec split -l 1000 {} {} \;
```

No loops required